# form input with email keyboard but no validation

Tags: forms, validation, input, bootstrap-4

I want to build a form (in bootstrap) that has an email or telephone number input field.
In mobile I want that field to open the "email keyboard" and I want it to don't validate if the value is an email.
This form also has some text inputs that I want them to be required.
What is the simple way for this to be achieved?

Comment: You don't want it to validate?

Comment: Just the email input field, not the hole form

Comment: Then simply use jQuery to validate your form's inputs but do not validate the email input..

Comment: I'm using jquery.min.js. Will I have to add an extra script "library" for validation?

Comment: And how do I make the mobile keyboard email open in that case @David Hope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to validate your form's inputs but DO NOT want to validate teh email input in the same form....

use something like this:

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).on('click', ".button", function(){
        var name = $(".name").val();
        var lastname = $(".lastname").val();
        var email = $(".email").val();

        if(name == "" || lastname == "" ){

        alert('Please fill in all the details')


        }else{


        ///////submit your form here... you can even use AJAX to submit yuour form////

    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form action="" method="post">

<input type="text" class="name">
<input type="text" class="lastname">
<input type="email" class="email">

</form>
```

YOU CAN USE ANY JQUERY LIB.

EDIT:

If you are using html5, the `<input type="email"` will automatically open the *'keypad email'*  on your device.

A working FIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/2v7ybe9h/2/

Based on the link you provided in the comments below, this is what it says:

[image]

They also provided an example in the same page...

As you can already see, the email input in that page has a `'required'` attribute and the `pattern` attribute.

If you simply remove those attributes, there wont be any "Verification" anymore.

**Example here:**

https://jsfiddle.net/2v7ybe9h/3/

You can also use the `novalidate` attribute on your form and simply validate your form using jQuery same as what i have provided you in the first fiddle.

**Example:**

https://jsfiddle.net/2v7ybe9h/4/

Comment: in my experiments with the type="email" also comes a validation that it requires the @ character to be in the value of the input. Is that validation gone in this example?

Comment: I haven't experienced the @ validation with only an input type="email"... Are you sure you don't have any other validations somewhere else?

Comment: check this out for confirmation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email . I'm only using boostrap 4 and mdb.js in my html

Comment: I also have required="true" in the email input field

Comment: then that is your answer... you simply remove the required="true" attribute.

Comment: I can see this working on the fiddle. I will try in my page

Comment: I have added a second fiddle with another example without the jQuery. That is based on the information provided in the link that you posted above... Good luck.

Comment: I removed the required="true" attribute but if the email input field has some value it keeps checking if it has the @ char. I believe this is bootstrap fault because the error message that it gives to me is in portuguese (not English) and my html has a lang="pt" attribute. it has to be bootstrap that is making that validation

Comment: @alexandre1985, view my last edit in my answer. you can use <form method="post" action="" novalidate>...</form>

Comment: it has to be with the novalidate and then javascript validation for the other fields. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The modern answer (as of 2020) is to use `inputmode`:

```
<input type="text" inputmode="email">
<input type="text" inputmode="tel">
```

[See MDN for more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode)